# Networkx Remove NaN Node in graph and its edges but keep the connected nodes

Tags: python, data-visualization, sequence, networkx

I want to visualize different sequences of data with Networkx. Not all sequences have a destination point but I want to show these "single" sequences as a single circle in the plot (if they also appear in a different sequence e.g. "A" also occures in "AB" then the "A"-Circle of the "AB" sequence should get bigger and there shouldnt appear another "A" Circle.).

My raw input data looks like this:

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| A | B |
| L |  |
| A |  |
| G | C |
| M | M |

My desired output with this example sequences looks like this (ignoring colors):

[image]

My code looks like this so far: (Right now the size of the nodes is depending on the amount of edges it has, I also want to change it to how often a Nodes appears in the data)

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

dataset = pd.read_csv(r'confidential_data.csv')
df = dataset.copy()

df = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(),as_index=False, dropna = False).size()
df['size'] = df['size'].div(100).round(2) #dividing by 100 because the thickness of the lines would get too big
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'source', 'target', edge_attr='size', create_using=nx.DiGraph() )


                                                  
                                                   
d = dict(G.degree)
 
widths = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'size')
nodelist = G.nodes()
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
 
pos = nx.shell_layout(G)
 
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,
                       nodelist=nodelist,
                       node_size= [v * 400 for v in d.values()],
                       node_color='orange',
                       alpha=0.7)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos = pos,
                       edgelist = widths.keys(),
                       width=list(widths.values()),
                       edge_color='blue',
                       alpha=0.6,)
 
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos,
                        labels=dict(zip(nodelist,nodelist)),
                        font_color='black')
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "size")
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=pos, edge_labels = edge_labels, label_pos=0.2,font_size=15)
 
plt.box(False)
 
plt.show()
```

with this my plot would look something like this with the example data:

[image]

here you see the single occurences "A" and "L" in the table refer to NaN. I dont want the connection to the NaN. Is there either a way to remove the node NaN with all its edges (without hurting the other nodes) or to plot data without a target point at all?

If you know a solution or maybe have a different kind of visualization in mind for this kind of data and problem, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!